# Flutter fadein animation always shows black screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to create a flutter application where the background image changes based off data coming in from an API. I have the following code written to have the screen fade in using an `AnimationController` and `Animation` of doubles, however whenever I try to load the app, all I get is a black screen.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(RootWidget());

class RootWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RootWidgetState createState() => _RootWidgetState();
}

class _RootWidgetState extends State<RootWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    _animation =
        Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
          parent: _controller,
          curve: Curves.easeOut
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
        home: AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: _animation.value,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Vuetiful Mobile'),
            ),
            body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/Sunny-photo.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover
                    )
                ),
                child: Container(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(100, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Temp', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                    )
                )
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either choose between using an `AnimationController` or the `AnimatedOpacity` widget, but not both.

`AnimatedOpacity` is already an animated version of opacity, so adding a controller to it doesn't do what you want; it handles all of the necessary animation logic itself. You just need to provide an opacity and it animates to it in the given duration and with the given curve.

The likely easier solution would be to stick with `AnimatedOpacity` and get rid of the controller. Then set the opacity value with a post frame callback:

```dart
class _RootWidgetState extends State<RootWidget> {
  double opacity = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        opacity = 1;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
        home: AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: opacity,
          curve: Curves.easeOut,//Add your curve here
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),//Set your desired duration
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Vuetiful Mobile'),
            ),
            body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/Sunny-photo.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover
                    )
                ),
                child: Container(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(100, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Temp', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                    )
                )
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

This solution also ends up being more efficient because flutter doesn't have to rebuild as much stuff for each tick.

---

Alternatively, you could keep the `AnimationController` and change `AnimatedOpacity` to `Opacity`:

```dart
class _RootWidgetState extends State<RootWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState((){});
    });
    _controller.forward();
    
    _animation =
        Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
          parent: _controller,
          curve: Curves.easeOut
        ));
   
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
        home: Opacity(
          opacity: _animation.value,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Vuetiful Mobile'),
            ),
            body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/Sunny-photo.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover
                    )
                ),
                child: Container(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(100, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text('Temp', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                    )
                )
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to flutter coming from Vue/React and it boggles my mind how complex it can get in certain areas, but I'm adamant on learning it.